# Javac cannot find SWT library despite correct classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, swt, javac

I have a Java project that uses SWT and compiles/runs perfectly.

When I try to compile via Ant, however, javac cannot find the SWT library despite the build.xml specifying the correct classpath.

The SWT library is located in `C:\my_work\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins\`.  As seen below (under the `javac` tags, this classpath is specified as such.

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project default="run" name="My Project">
<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java classname="com.company.program.project">
        <classpath path="staging\" location="C:\my_work\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins\"/>
    </java>
</target>
<target name="compile">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src" destdir="staging">
    <classpath path="C:\my_work\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins\"></classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<jar destfile="./build/jars/swtgui.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
     <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.swtgui.MainGui" />
      <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
    </manifest>

    <fileset dir="./bin/com/company/program/project" includes="**/*.class" />
    <fileset dir="C:\my_work\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins\" includes="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.6.0.v3650b.jar" />

</jar>
<record name="./MyProject.log" loglevel="verbose" action="start"/>
```

The above gives me errors on import statements such as the following:

```
error: package org.eclipse.swt does not exist
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
                      ^
```

Why does javac not find the SWT library when the classpath is correctly specified?

Also how can I find out where javac is looking?  The logs -- even in verbose mode -- tell me nothing about where javac is trying to find these import statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems `<classpath path="C:\my_work\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins\"></classpath>` is not adding dependencies to compile classpath

this way works for me:

```
<target name="compile">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src" destdir="staging">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="C:\my_work\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins">
                <!-- <include name="**/*.jar" /> -->
                <include name="org.eclipse.swt.*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Comment: Your change worked, but the run target doesnt execute now. The jar file is also not  being created. Do I need to do something similar to get that to work?

Answer (score 2):

SWT provides a separate Jar for standalone Java applications.

You can download the latest one from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.8-201806110500/) - look at the 'SWT Binary and Source' section near the bottom of the page.